# python script not running in shell

Tags: python, shell

OS X

I have a properly shebanged (`#!/usr/bin/python`) Python helloworld script at `/bin/games`, which doesn't run. No errors - the shell just proceeds to read my next command. Is there anything I've missed?

So far I've checked the following:

1. my shebang works for other Python scripts
2. $PATH includes `/bin/games`, so `command not found` isn't the case
3. the script file's access permissions are 754.

Latest discovery: it runs with `sudo`. But I want to execute it just like any other command.

Latest discovery #2: now that I made another script in `/bin/games`, it runs normally and the old one does not, although they've been both 755'ed.

Here's the script itself as required:

`#!/usr/local/bin/python
print 'hello world'`

Comment: does normal users have read and execute access to the file too?

Comment: Another, less relevant discovery: `which python -a` yields `/usr/local/bin/python`, but all other scripts run just fine and this particular script doesn't trigger the "bad interpreter" error.

Comment: try 755 access permission

Comment: @Azad tried it; no effect

Comment: which PATH contains /bin/games normal user or root?

Comment: @Azad I think I might understand the distinction, but how do I check that? I just exported this directory to the $PATH so it contains it now.

Comment: did you do it in a root shell or normal shell? try `echo $PATH` as normal user

Comment: and check whether you can run your script by full path i.e `/bin/games/script`

Comment: Sorry for a noob Q, but how do I do that? I did that from my default user (just `echo $PATH`), and it said `/bin/games` is valid.

Comment: type `/bin/games/your-script-name`

Comment: try `chmod a+x` and then launch your script

Comment: @MartinBeseda did that, thanks. No effect either. I'm still curious about what did I just do, though, but I couldn't fully decipher the manpage. Could you please briefly explain this `a+x` mode?

Comment: @AlexAgapov It means ADD (+) the right to EXECUTE (x) to ALL (a).

Comment: @MartinBeseda Thank you! But haven't I already done this by `chmod 755`?

Comment: @AlexAgapov It was pretty similar, but you've set even read rights to everyone and write right to the owner.

Comment: @MartinBeseda sure, but that can't be the source of the problem, right? Everyone's got the right to execute things because of 5, and I don't mind the FBI reading my hello world program. But still it doesn't run!

Comment: @AlexAgapov What's the output of `ls -l your_script`?

Comment: @MartinBeseda rwx-r-xr-x for both scripts, just as `chmod 755` told it to be :)

Comment: @AlexAgapov Try to paste your code to the question, maybe the problem is, something in it can't be run without root privileges.

Comment: @MartinBeseda did it

Comment: Have you tried to use `strace` to understand what's going on?

Comment: @Maxime nope, I don't have this utility on OS X. Anyway, what kind of info would I get that way? Maybe it's worth finding an alternative in this case

Comment: `strace` print all the system calls made by the program. In your case, that would be useful in order to see if an open failed or when does it stop running. I'm sorry, I don't know OS X to help.

Comment: @Maxime thank you, I'll see what I can find in replacement for my OS.

Comment: @Maxime here is what `dtruss`, the OS X analogue, said:
`failed to execute mygame: file is set-id or unreadable`
(`mygame` is the script name)